# Reusing password to unlock KeePassXC database and ask user for new password when adding new KeePassXC entry password

Tags: bash, password, keepassxc

I do have an issue passing on password to `keepassxc-cli` in bash.  I would like it to unlock and ask for adding a password on KeePassXC entry.

When I ask user for a password e.g. `read` for KeePassXC DB password and I use it to unlock it multiple times:

**This works:**

```
echo $passwordForKeepassDatabase | keepassxc-cli add "$keepassxcDatabase" "$databaseGroup/$databaseEntry $currentYear"
```

However, when I need to unlock the KeePassXC DB and simultaneously ask the user for the entry password it does not work.  The KeePassXC DB password is used in both cases.

**The following does not work correctly** (as it uses the DB password for both prompt - notice the added `-p` switch):

```
echo $passwordForKeepassDatabase | keepassxc-cli -p add "$keepassxcDatabase" "$databaseGroup/$databaseEntry $currentYear"
```

Any idea for a workaround?

I would like to re-use the already entered KeePassXC DB password and then ask the user to enter a password for the new KeePassXC entry.